Assigning std::make_unique<derived> to unique_ptr<base> failed
I'm trying to use polymorphism to implement different working mode, but there's something wrong with my implementation and I always get the same error:
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::unique_ptr<srsran::test_mode_buffer_size>’ and 
‘std::_MakeUniq<srsran::static_test_mode>::__single_object’ 
{aka ‘std::unique_ptr<srsran::static_test_mode, std::default_delete<srsran::static_test_mode> >’})
  533 |     buffer_size_container = std::make_unique<static_test_mode>();

Here's my definition of base class and derived class:
class static_test_mode : public test_mode_buffer_size {
public:
  static_test_mode() {}
  ~static_test_mode() {}
  unsigned get_buffer_size() override {
    return TEST_UE_DL_BUFFER_STATE_UPDATE_SIZE;
  }
};

class range_test_mode : public test_mode_buffer_size {
public:
  range_test_mode(srs_du::du_test_config::test_ue_config _test_ue):
  test_ue(_test_ue), interval_counter(0){
    current = test_ue.min_buffer_size;
  }
  ~range_test_mode() {}
  unsigned get_buffer_size() override {
    ++interval_counter;
    if(interval_counter == test_ue.buffer_interval && 
      current + test_ue.buffer_step <= test_ue.max_buffer_size){
      current += test_ue.buffer_step;
    }
    return current;
  }
private:
  srs_du::du_test_config::test_ue_config test_ue;
  unsigned interval_counter,current;
};
// TODO: trace mode

class test_mode_buffer_size{
public:
  virtual ~test_mode_buffer_size() = default;
  virtual unsigned get_buffer_size() = 0;
};

Here's my constructor and it says no match for operator= between unique_ptr and make_unique.
class mac_test_mode_adapter{
  //other members
  std::unique_ptr<test_mode_buffer_size> buffer_size_container;
}

mac_test_mode_adapter::mac_test_mode_adapter(const srs_du::du_test_config::test_ue_config& test_ue_cfg_, mac_result_notifier& phy_notifier_) :
  test_ue(test_ue_cfg_),
  phy_notifier(std::make_unique<phy_test_mode_adapter>(phy_notifier_)),
  ue_info_mgr(test_ue.rnti, test_ue.nof_ues)
{
  //fmt::print("test_ue.buffer_size={}\n",test_ue.buffer_size);
  if(test_ue.working_mode == "static"){
    buffer_size_container = std::make_unique<static_test_mode>();
  }
  else if (test_ue.working_mode == "range"){
    buffer_size_container = std::make_unique<range_test_mode>(test_ue);
  }
  // TODO: trace mode
}

How can I solve this error?

Please try to create a [mre] to show us. Such an assignment should work fine, which means there's either something wrong with your compiler (highly unlikely) or there's something in the code you're not showing us that causes the problem.

By the way, what compiler are you using? What version of it? What options and flags are you providing when building?

Without even looking at the code: this can happen if you're doing this in context where the classes are forward-declared but the definitions are not visible. If I'm wrong, pleas emake a proper [mcve] that we can compile and see the same error.

My complier is gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2).

I tried to write a simple test file and this error still exists.`#include 
#include 
using namespace std;
class B : public A {
public:
B(){}
~B(){}
void F() override{ cout<<0<<endl;}
};
class A {
public:
virtual ~A() = default;
virtual void F() = 0;
};
class C {
public:
C(){
objA = make_unique();
}
unique_ptr objA;
};
int main()
{
C c;
return 0;
}`

While you should add such code in the question itself (please [edit] it), it's possible to see that the problem is exactly what @HolyBlackCat said. You're using forward declarations but need actual definitions. Order matters.

Your MCVE makes it very obvious: You cannot derive class B from class A if class A isn't defined before (above of) class B. Even a forward declaration is not sufficient for class inheritance. Just re-ordering the definitions solves the issue: Fixed MCVE

thx, error gets solved. How can I forgot this LMAO
